# how to dialog intent to next activity with custom list view

Tags: android

how to dialog intent to next activity with custom list view . i have a dialog but i dont know how to intent to next activiy anyone have somehow can u tell me Thanks you

public class maincard extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menucard);



    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    /*** Rows 1 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ImageID", "1");
    //map.put("ImageDesc", "Sea View1");
    map.put("ImagePath", "pic_a");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 2 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ImageID", "2");
    //map.put("ImageDesc", "Sea View2");
    map.put("ImagePath", "pic_b");
    MyArrList.add(map); 

    /*** Rows 3 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ImageID", "3");
    //map.put("ImageDesc", "Sea View 3");
    map.put("ImagePath", "pic_c");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 4 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ImageID", "4");
    //map.put("ImageDesc", "Sea View 4");
    map.put("ImagePath", "pic_d");
    MyArrList.add(map);         

    // listView1
    final ListView lstView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); 

    lstView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MyArrList));

    // OnClick

    final AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    lstView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogpreviewcard,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);


            int ResID = getResources().getIdentifier(MyArrList.get(position).get("ImagePath"), "drawable", maincard.this.getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(ResID);

           //imageDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);   
            imageDialog.setTitle("View : " + MyArrList.get(position).get("ImageDesc"));
            imageDialog.setView(layout);
            imageDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {






          }

            });
            imageDialog.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }

            });


            AlertDialog  alert = imageDialog.create();
            alert.show();



        }

    });

}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        context = c;
        MyArr = list;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MyArr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardcolumm, null); 
        }

        // ColImage
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        int ResID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(MyArr.get(position).get("ImagePath"), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(ResID);

        // ColPosition
        TextView txtPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgID);
        txtPosition.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        txtPosition.setText("ID : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageID"));

        // ColPicname
        TextView txtPicName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgDesc);
        txtPicName.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
        txtPicName.setText("Desc : " + MyArr.get(position).get("ImageDesc"));


        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Send your Data like this:

```
 imageDialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()   {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent n = new Intent(SourCeActivity.this , Destination.class);
            n.putExtra("Key" , MyArrList.get(position).get("ImagePath"));
            startActivity(n);
  }
```

And retrieve this value to next Activity:

```
 Intent n = getIntent();
 String xyz = n.getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: oh sorry my eng bad

i need click menu item 

press pic_a > dialog ok ==   go  activity card1
pic_b go > dialog ok == go Actvity card2

Comment: because you will get image path from arraylist after OK button pressed of dialog

Comment: if this answer useful for you then vote up or accept as a answer so other can also get solution from here......Thanks also

Comment: @KaneSmithSillapasit if you can't vote up...you can accept this atnswer as right click

Comment: thanks and i have new problem about inset gallery

when i inset and pick it image not show
then i click again image show up

u know how to refresh it ?

Comment: yes 1st time not show then i click at image again ll show

i use image.onclick